# Pattern for attribute values history

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, database-design

There is any pattern that allows me to save the historical values of an attribute?

Image that I have an object:

```
public class Object {
   public State state;
}
```

Every time I change the value of state I should store the date of the change and the author?

How is the best way to store these values?
Should I use an auxiliary table?

Comment: Does this help? 
https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/AuditLog.html

Comment: why did you need to saving the history?

Comment: @fujy I'm already using the Audit for security reasons, log every change on my system.

Comment: @Victor So why the auditing is not enough to track your object history states?

Comment: @holi-java, I want to build some historical views of the changes. Something like our reputation here using graphs and timelines.

Comment: @fujy Because these information should be part of the data model.

Comment: @Victor you can introduce a middle man to change the `state` , and then recording the information what you need. let's say an `Action` , everybody update the `state` via the `Action`.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)?  The "undo" facet is probably not what you are looking for, although the general use of the pattern is to record state history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple technical approach to achieve your scenarios, below two approaches can be used

1. By maintained version column in the table ( for every update insert new row with increased version)
2. By maintained history table ( for every update move old data to history table and update the current value in entity table)

---

I choose the second solution and it looks a good solution.

[image]